# Ошибка в счёте простых чисел

Tags: python

При вызове вложенной функции schetdel выдаёт ошибку об отсутствии значения переменной d (хотя она обозначена во внешней функции)
Задача: посчитать количество простых чисел в данном списке

```
kolvo=int(input()) #длина списка
arr=[]
arr=str(input())
arr=arr.split()
print (arr[3]) #проверка работает ли то, что сверху
y=0

def schetdel (i):
    if arr[d]%i==0:
        x+=1  #счетчик делений

def prost():
    d=0
    while d<kolvo:
        arr[d]=int(arr[d])
       for i in range (arr[d]) : 
            schetdel (i)
        d+=1

        if x==2: 
             y+=1 #счетчик простых чисел

    prost ()

print (y)
```

Comment: В функции `prost()` `d` - это локальная переменная и её область видимости ограничена телом функции. В функции `schetdel (i)` переменная d - не определена, поэтому возникает ошибка.

Comment: Потом возникнет такая же ошибка с переменной х.

Comment: вам надо разобраться с областью видимости переменных. Дальше по коду аналогичные ошибки с `x` в `schetdel` и  `y` в `prost`.
Прочтите хотя бы [это](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/faq.html).

Answer (score 1):

У вас в коде проблемы с областью видимости переменных. Например, когда вы определяется переменную `d` в функции `prost()`, то область видимости этой переменной ограничена телом функции и вы не можете вызывать её за пределами функции. То же самое касается переменной `x`.

Вот небольшой код для проверки чисел из списка. Для проверки простых чисел используется решето Эратосфена, код взят из этого [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188425/is-there-a-simple-algorithm-that-can-determine-if-x-is-prime-and-not-confuse-a/193605#193605)

```
arr=str(input("Элементы списка: ")) # вводим элементы массива через пробел
arr = arr.split()
arr = [int(i) for i in arr] # преобразуем строки в числа

# Функция, реализующая решето Эратосфена
def iprimes_upto(limit):
    is_prime = [True] * limit
    for n in range(2, limit):
        if is_prime[n]:
           yield n
           for i in range(n*n, limit, n): # start at ``n`` squared
               is_prime[i] = False

primes = list(iprimes_upto(max(arr))) # Список простых чисел до макс. элемента массива

count = 0
for i in arr: 
    if i in primes: # если число в массиве простых чисел
        count = count + 1 # увеличиваем счётчик на 1

print(count)
```